# AJAX request on Node.js server

Tags: html, ajax, json, node.js

I am  unable to make an AJAX request from my `.html` page to my `node.js` server for a `JSON` file. I've been reading on `AJAX` requests, but all I am able to make out is how to display the servers responseText.

It would be great if you could help me out, it would be even better if you could link me some tutorials on this, anyway this is what I've got at this moment:

### server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    var arr = new Array();
    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('info.json'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });
 
    rd.on('line', function(line) {
        arr.push(line);
    }).on('close', function(){
        res.send(arr);
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('test2.html',function (err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

### test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function sendAjax(){
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                }

                xmlHttp.open("GET", "/test", true);
                xmlHttp.send();
            }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="submit" onClick="sendAjax()" value="SendAjax" />
        <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know this may not look like much, I've been struggling with this, and the book I have (Node.js in Action) doesn't help me alot. But as I said, what I want is to display the .json info in the browser. Thx for reading

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get any errors in the JS console? Does your browser's developer tools Net tab show the HTTP request being sent? Does it show the response? Are they what you expect?

Comment: +1 to @Quentin's comment. Is it working when you open it on the browser directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you may replace

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

with

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
    html += '<div>' + parsed[i] + '</div>';
}
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = html;
```

You may also try to replace

```
res.send(arr);
```

with

```
res.json(arr);
```

**Update**
Or maybe you just forgot to write this line in the beginning of server.js:

```
var readline = require('readline');
```